# Problem with showing that any nonempty open subset of plane is not contained in countable sum of segments and usage of this fact

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets

I have a problem with showing the fact which states that **none of nonempty subset of plane is not contained in countable sum of segments**. It seems to be trivial, but maybe my intuition is wrong. Anyway I have no idea how to write it down formally.

Before I will describe the second problem I have to remind that a set is **very dense** when $G\cap U$ is uncountable for every nonempty  open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2.$

With this knowledge I was trying to prove that there exists such borel set $G$ which is very dense and its complemention is very dense, too.

My attempt:

We assume that there exists borel set $G$ which is very dense, that is $G\cap U$ is uncountable for every nonempty open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2.$ We have to show that $G^C$ is very dense, that is $G^C\cap U$ is uncountable for every nonempty open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2.$ Knowing that  **none of nonempty subset of plane is not contained in countable sum of segments** we have that $U$ must be uncountable, so $G^C\cap U$ is uncountable, too.

Is my reasoning correct? It seems to be too easy, so I think it's not correct.

I appreciate any help and advices.

Comment: I mean "segments" by "sections". Sorry for wrong nomenclature, I have already edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just let $\Bbb P=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and take $G=\Bbb P\times\Bbb P$? Every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^2$ contains a set of the form $\{x\}\times(a,b)$ for some $x\in\Bbb P$, which clearly intersects $G$ in an uncountable set, and a set of the form $\{q\}\times(a,b)$ for some $q\in\Bbb Q$, which is uncountable and contained in $\Bbb R^2\setminus G$, so $G$ and $\Bbb R^2\setminus G$ are very dense in $\Bbb R^2$. And

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb P\times\Bbb P&=(\Bbb P\times\Bbb R)\cap(\Bbb R\times\Bbb P)\\
&=\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}\big((\Bbb R\setminus\{q\})\times\Bbb R\big)\cap\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}\big(\Bbb R\times(\Bbb R\setminus\{q\})\big)
\end{align*}$$

is clearly a $G_\delta$ in $\Bbb R^2$, hence Borel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I ask what does $G_{\delta}$ mean?

Comment: @Novice: A $G_\delta$-set is the intersection of countably many open sets.